# jstl <c:if> tags not working in jsp file, getting error in tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl, tomcat7

I have problem using jstl tag `<c:if>` in jsp file. Basically I should make this as 2 questions although they are related.

#### The first question:

In my WEB-INF/lib, I put a jstl 1.2.jar

In my jsp file, I put this `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`.

In my jsp file, I use the `<c:if>` to do something. If the condition is true, it will shows some special message

Basically the contents inside `<c:if>` is not working, because the message is not shown even the condition is true.

But if I changed to use the older namespace, `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>`. Others are not changed, then the if tag is working, because the message inside the if tag is shown.

My first question is why I have to use /jstl instead of /jsp/jstl in namespace. I am using jstl1.2.jar. so I am supposed to use the newer uri for 1.2. however, older uri works but not newer uir.

#### The second question:

I ignore the first question I have, and just use /jstl as my namespace just because it makes my web app work the way I want. However, when I deploy my web app into tomcat 7.X, it shows exceptions as the following:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /mywebapp.jsp (line: 35, column: 10)
>   According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test
>   does not accept any expressions 
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)

in /mywebapp.jsp line:35, column:10, that is < c:if> tag.

If I change the namespace from  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%> to  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>, it can deploy in tomcat successfully but the functionality inside of < c:if> tag is not useful. other codes outside of `<c:if>` tag work though.

So I am very confused and really want to know how to fix this.

By the way, I am using servlet 2.5, jsp 2.0, jstl 1.2. I did try to upgrade the jsp2.0 to jsp2.1 in order to see if I can fix the first problem, but I have no idea how to upgrade jsp version.

Comment: I would venture a guess that your if syntax is incorrect. I would suggest post your code so we can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But if I changed to use the older namespace, `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>`. others are not changed, then the if tag is working, because the message inside the if tag is shown.*

That can happen if you have a `standard.jar` of JSTL 1.0 in the `/WEB-INF/lib`. Get rid of it. See also [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I by the way assume that you've untouched Tomcat's and JRE's own `/lib` folders and have not dropped any JSTL-related JARs in there, or have extracted the JSTL JAR's contents in a careless attempt to solve the problem.

---

> *By the way, I am using servlet 2.5, jsp 2.0, jstl 1.2. I did try to upgrade the jsp2.0 to jsp2.1 in order to see if I can fix the first problem, but I have no idea how to upgrade jsp version. I am very new to programming.*

You should absolutely not provide any Servlet or JSP libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` yourself. The servlet container (in your case, Tomcat) already ships with it. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

You only need to make sure that your `web.xml` root declaration complies whatever your servlet container supports. [Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), so your `web.xml` root declaration should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and I just got it to work as described below. I do not know if this solution is fitted for everyone, but it did work for me. I am a novice in java, so it might not be the best solution.

STL JSP Error Fix - Jar File location for JSTL

1.
Change
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
TO:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

2.
Download below jar files and
COPY them to …/WEB-INF/lib folder.

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.7/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.7.jar

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.6/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.6.jar