# No tag “if” defined in tag library imported with prefix “c”

Tags: spring, tomcat, jstl, tomcat7

I have a jsp file in which spring tags are used.

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> 
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 


     <c:if  test="${!empty employeeList}"> 
  <table class="data"> 
 <tr> 
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>LastName</th> 
<th>Email</th> 
<th>Telephone</th> 
<th>Action</th> 
</tr> 
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="emp"> 
<tr> 
    <td>${emp.firstname}</td> 
    <td>${emp.lastname}</td>
    <td>${emp.email}</td> 
    <td>${emp.telephone}</td> 
    <td><a href="delete/${emp.id}">Delete</a>|
        <a href="update/${emp.id}">Update</a>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
 </c:forEach> 
 </table> 
 </c:if>
```

It is giving me error that i have mentioned as title. I am running this code on tomcat 7 but I am not getting this error if I run it on jBoss 7. It is driving me nuts. Kindly help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jstl <c:if> tags not working in jsp file, getting error in tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573725/jstl-cif-tags-not-working-in-jsp-file-getting-error-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: why kind of error? you did't mentioned, how can we help you. Did you imported JSTL on your POM.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of error do you get but i think that you just have no javax.servlet imported. Try to add to your pom.xml dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Tomcat is just servlet container without additional jars. JBoss is more powerful server and has almost all JEE libraries build in so it could be reason that it works on JBoss and doesn't work on Tomcat